# clang: export symbols of implicitly instantiated functions with O3

Tags: c++, linker, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

TL,DR: **How can I force clang to export the symbols of implicitly instantiated functions even when -O3 is active?**

Let's take the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <llvm/Support/DynamicLibrary.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/RTDyldMemoryManager.h>

template <typename T>
__attribute__((noinline))
int twice(const T& t) {
    return t * 2;
}

int thrice(const int& t) {
    return t * 3;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << twice(5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << thrice(5) << std::endl;

    llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::LoadLibraryPermanently(nullptr);  // Make symbols from current process visible
    std::cout << "address of twice: " << llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess("__Z5twiceIiEiRKT_") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "address of thrice: " << llvm::RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess("__Z6thriceRKi") << std::endl;
}
```

There are two functions, twice and thrice. The first is templated, the second is not. I first call them regularly, then I try to get their address using libLLVM. Think of it as part of a super simplified JIT compiler (that has a mangler that comes up with the name).

With `clang++ -O0 -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/ jit.cpp -lLLVM` (clang version 6.0.0 on OS X), the output is as expected:

```
10
15
address of twice: 4350763184
address of thrice: 4350762224
```

If I enable optimization, the symbol for `twice` does not get exported anymore, as seen in `nm a.out | grep twice`:

```
00000001000010b0 T __Z5twiceIiEiRKT_ (with -O0)
00000001000009c0 t __Z5twiceIiEiRKT_ (with -O3)
```

As a result, libLLVM does not find the function anymore:

```
10
15
address of twice: 0
address of thrice: 4315621072
```

With gcc, the symbols get exported.

I can get clang to export the symbol if I explicitly instantiate it:

```
template int twice<int>(const int& t);
```

That, however, is not really an option, as we don't know which instantiations will be called by the JIT engine.

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247906/why-are-only-some-of-these-c-template-instantiations-exported-in-a-shared-libr), but it only deals with explicit instantiations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add attribute `used`, like this:

```
template <typename T>
__attribute__((used))
int twice(const T& t) {
    return t * 2;
}
```

That will force Clang to export the symbol.