# Placing C++ template definition for a class member function in CPP file with IMPLICIT instantiation instead of .H allowed?

Tags: c++

Given code like the following:

foo.cpp

```
#include"foo.h"

template <int X>
void bar::foo(){
 cout << X << endl;
}

static void tea(){
 bar().foo<1>();
 bar().foo<2>();
 bar().foo<3>();
}
```

foo.h

```
class bar {
 public:
  template <int X>
  void foo();
};
```

main.cpp

```
...
bar().foo<1>();
bar().foo<2>();
bar().foo<3>();
...
```

Is such a pattern allowed in any version of C++?

Edit:

Why is this disallowed when explicit instantiation with `template void bar::foo<1>()` (and etc) would allow this to link correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ compilers are not required to actually generate symbols for anything unless you force it with an extern declaration. They aggresively inline functions, which might remove all evidence of your instantiation. I tried out your example, and it linked with `-O0`, but not with `-O3`.

Comment: Thank you! I had not considered optimization at all when I was trying to figure out why this seemed to sometimes compile and sometimes not!

Comment: With the guidance of this comment I found this!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211379/clang-export-symbols-of-implicitly-instantiated-functions-with-o3